# Cannot execute ClickOnce deployment manifest

Tags: deployment, manifest, clickonce

I accidentally changed file extension association of "ClickOnce Deployment Manifest" files (*.application) with some other application, from right-click/openWith in Windows 11.

Normally, it should execute the deployment manifest and open the "ClickOnce install application" dialog.

Now, I don't know which application to associate to get back to what it was earlier. Any ideas?